# Get scrollTop in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reasons I have this CSS styles:

```
body {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

In Firefox: $('body').scrollTop() = 743;
But in Chrome: $('body').scrollTop() = 0;

A jsFiddle for testing is here: http://jsfiddle.net/uFCCU/

How to get scrollTop of the "body" in webkit browsers?

Comment: There are two answers here that seem to answer your question, you should accept one of them. If they don't, you should comment on why they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out exactly why it doesn't work with the CSS you have, but if you change your CSS to

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then `$(document).scrollTop()` gives you the right values in FF and chrome http://jsfiddle.net/uFCCU/1/

It has the same effect of what you were trying to do (I think) and doesn't do anything weird like making the body absolutely positioned. I had never seen that in 15 years of web development.

Comment: I want to solve "scrollbar-deactivation" issue when modal box appeared. http://jsfiddle.net/uFCCU/3/ (you can see that scrollbar is under "overlay-div"). Supposed that I can't make new inner wrapper to body, because some external scripts appends absolute box to body, and I can't use body {overflow: hidden; margin-left: -16px;} for hiding scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but the style for `html` actually does **nothing** at all other than **messing up webkit**.

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

Simply remove it.

Comment: I can't remove it. See: http://jsfiddle.net/uFCCU/3/ (scrollbar of the page is under overlay and modal box)

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko I usually wrap another `<div>` around the content.

Comment: some social widget (http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=Like) appends to body some absolute position "div". With and without "wrap-div": http://jsfiddle.net/uFCCU/5/  http://jsfiddle.net/uFCCU/4/