# scrollTop and html overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

When a CSS rule is set like this

```
html { overflow: hidden; }
```

I can't get or set scroll position in Chrome using javascript anymore (only `DOMElement.scrollIntoView` is working).

When I remove it it works but it messes up the whole page containing a "parallax effect" created with CSS3. Here is a reduced example (only prefixed with -webkit-): http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/LxCxn/

Comment: perhaps you can try custom js scrollbars and hide them, see if that works?

Comment: You try variant when you use `var scrollHeight = document.querySelector('#second').offsetTop;` and then you method `window.scrollTo(0, scrollHeight)` when you need.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but found some [documentation](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php) that document.body.scrollTop will always return 0 in Chrome.

[Similar on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948345/get-scrolltop-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using the clearfix to do "layout preversing" the same way overflow: hidden does.

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";    
  display: block;    
  height: 0;    
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {zoom: 1;} /* IE < 8 */
```

add class="clearfix" class to the parent, and remove overflow: hidden;